# error trying to use LWC light DOM (Beta) on local server

Tags: lightning-web-components, light-dom, lwc-local-development

I'm trying to load a sample LWC using the Light DOM (Beta)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_light_dom

I've stripped it down to essentially their example and I still get the following error on running it on the local server:

```
Invalid directive "$lwc:render-mode" on element <template>.
```

My component:

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">

    <p>Hello World</p>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    export default class TestForm extends LightningElement {
    static renderMode = 'light';

}
```

API version of the component is set to 57.0

Comment: And just to be clear, you mean loading locally as described here correct? https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/set-up-lwc-local-dev

Comment: @BryanAnderson yep

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I think the problem is the API version of the local dev server. I just installed the local dev plugin for the first time on my computer and when it started up I got

```
Starting LWC Local Development.
Username: drewcpu@gmail.com
Api Version: 49.0
```

I'm not sure Salesforce has updated the local dev server since Summer '20. Perhaps they'll update it when Light DOM is GA?